# Voltage Spike/Noise due to Switching

Tags: relay, oscilloscope, ldo, test-equipment

I am currently looking over a PCB and performing a spike check on the device of interest.  The device itself has a 7V maximum rating on a pin and I am seeing a strange behavior resulting in a 17-18V spike/switching noise.  The scope shot is shown below:
[image]

At first glance, it appeared to be a spike when I look at the full spectrum (shown below), but it is not a spike since it is approximately 150us burst width.  A regular spike would appear to be much shorter in time.  Since there is relays and capacitors between the power supplies, could it be a relay sticking and having a hard time switching off?  Have anyone seen behaviors like this before?

[image]

Comment: Inductance switching off does this without a clamp diode. Do you know?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 What do you mean?  I have clamp diodes in parallel with every relay.

Comment: Yes across every coil

Comment: Remember that part about inductors voltage going to infinity after the inductor is 'charged' and the impedance of the circuit is open? It doesn't 'go to infinity' but the voltage can get quite large.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a schematic of the circuit and identify where you are measuring, it might be easier to say, but I speculate since you mentioned relays, that this is flyback caused when an inductive load is disconnected.  If you don't already have flyback diodes anti-parallel to the relay coils, try adding that.

If it is from the relay, you could be seeing the extended and repeated pulses as the contacts separate, essentially bounce.

Comment: I have flyback diodes on every relays of the PCB.  Just inspected the board and nothing is wrong.  Could be a power supply/system issue.  I will check if I can see the spike before the relay as well.

Comment: Do you see this noise only when relays switch, or at other times?  Can you correlate the noise with certain events, so you can narrow down the cause?

Comment: Yes noise is usually when LDO is turned off.  Maybe something to do with the part itself.

Comment: Or maybe something powered by that LDO producing this noise as it loses power.

Answer (score 1):

Without a schematic  we can only speculate, but there's one trap that's worth mentioning.

It's common practice - and essential - to protect switches with inductive loads - like relays - with diodes to limit inductive spikes to the supply voltage. The trap comes if you don't pay enough attention to the capabilities of that supply.

Many power supplies are not protected against being fed with higher voltages - they can supply current, but not sink it. Thus an inductive spike, on a lightly loaded supply, can momentarily pull the supply voltage higher.

Check this doesn't apply to your design.